# Ajax request in a PHP MVC-structure

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest

I´m building a small PHP MVC structure where I separate the application in 2 root folders:

**1. /app/** 
Containing Model-, View-, and Controller-files and some Core- and Application-specific files.

**2. /public/**
Containing css, javascripts, images etc.

**The access to the /app/** **folder** is forbidden in .htaccess with:

```
Options -Indexes
```

My concern here is how do I implement Ajax/XMLHttpRequest(Get) here:

1. Say I want to call a PHP-file with XMLHttpRequest.
2. The PHP-file queries a MySQL-database (using a Model)
3. The data from the database is returned to the Ajax-request.

***Is it possible to reach the /app/-folder with Javascript code that is in the /public/-folder if the access is restricted in .htaccess-file ??***

Thanks.

Comment: Look at how other frameworks does this. It's common to have an index file in the public dir that bootstraps an application that lives outside the public dir (app or src folder). The index file acts as a front controller which all requests are routed to. With a setup like this you should be able to query an url that will be routed to the front controller which in turn loads the appropriate controller for the current request

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the scripts of the /app/ folder from the client browser using XMLHttpRequest because `Options -Indexes` doesn't restrict access to scripts, it only tells apache that if someone access the folder /app/ it shouldn't display it contents by creating a nice index of the files in it.